# how is distance between two addresses computed?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, byte, sizeof

I would like to compute the number of bytes between two addresses.

```
uint32_t length = &b - &a;
```

[image]

When a and b are uint32_t, length is 1.

```
uint32_t a, b;
uint32_t length = &b - &a;  // length is one
```

When a and b are uint8_t, length is 4.

```
uint8_t a, b;
uint32_t length = &b - &a;  // length is four
```

The computation, therefore, is the number of uint32_t or uint8_t between a and b, not the mathematical difference between the addresses as I falsely expected.

My question: What part of the C language covers computation of addresses?   Can someone reference a location in the spec that discusses the topic?

Comment: Technically, pointer arithmetic between pointers not pointing within the same object is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Pointers all have a type. What kind of thing do they point to? The difference between two pointers is the number of *things* between them , not bytes.

Comment: Curious, why does code use type `uint32_t` for `uint32_t length = &b - &a;` instead of maybe `int`, `long long`, or `ptrdiff_t`?

Comment: On some systems, different objects might be placed in [different memory segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Protected_mode_segments.svg) and might then not have a distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointer subtraction is covered in section 6.5.6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *3* For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - **both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible complete object types;** or
> - the left operand is a pointer to a complete object type and the right operand has integer type.
>
> ...
>
> *9* **When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements.** The size of the result is implementation-defined, and
>   its type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t defined in the
>    header. If the result is not representable in an object of
>   that type, the behavior is undefined. In other words, if the
>   expressions P and Q point to, respectively, the i-th and j-th elements
>   of an array object, the expression (P)-(Q) has the value i−j provided
>   the value fits in an object of type ptrdiff_t. Moreover, if the
>   expression P points either to an element of an array object or one
>   past the last element of an array object, and the expression Q points
>   to the last element of the same array object, the expression
>   ((Q)+1)-(P) has the same value as ((Q)-(P))+1 and as -((P)-((Q)+1)),
>   and has the value zero if the expression P points one past the last
>   element of the array object, even though the expression (Q)+1 does not
>   point to an element of the array object.

So the difference is the number of *elements* between the two, not the number of bytes.

Note that this only allows subtracting pointers between two elements of the same array.  So this is legal:

```
uint32_t a[5];
uint32_t len = &a[1] - &a[0];
```

But this is not:

```
uint32_t a, b
uint32_t len = &b - &a;
```

Answer (score 1):

in the standard compliant C pointer arithmentics is not allowed if the pointers have different types or not point to the same memory block (ie table or allocated other way). Otherwise it is the UB

But if the variables are located in the same continuous address space - for example in the ARM uC result of this arithmetics will be defined if pointes have the same type or you cast them to the same type.

**this is nor C standard compliant code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


uint64_t c;
uint64_t d;
uint16_t e;
uint8_t f;


int main(void)
{   uint32_t a,b;
    printf("%lld\n", (long long)((uint8_t *)&b - (uint8_t *)&a));
    printf("%lld\n", (long long)((uint8_t *)&c - (uint8_t *)&a));
    printf("%lld\n", (long long)((uint8_t *)&d - (uint8_t *)&c));
    printf("%lld\n", (long long)((uint8_t *)&e - (uint8_t *)&d));
    printf("%lld\n", (long long)((uint8_t *)&f - (uint8_t *)&c));
}
```

What will be printed is 100% up to implementation. Some of the results might have sense another not.

This kind of arithmetic is used in the embedded development for example by defining the symbols in the linker script (for example start of bss and end of bss) and then those symbols (their addresses actually) are used to do something like zeroing the bss or initializing the data segment

You can try it on Linux machine:
https://ideone.com/dm0R5M

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to compute the number of bytes between two addresses.

If the addresses are in the same array, code can subtract pointers to get a count of the number of elements in the difference.  Then multiply by the size of the type to report the number of "bytes".

```
ptrdiff_t diff = &a[some_index] - &a[some__other_index];
diff *= sizeof a[0];
printf("Diff %td\n", diff);
```

---

If the address of 2 objects are not known to be in the same array, code can carefully subtract, yet depending on the memory model, the difference may or may not represent the "byte" difference.   IAC, the below avoids *undefined behavior*.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *va = &a;
void *vb = &b;
// optional types
uintptr_t ua = (uintptr_t)va;
uintptr_t ub = (uintptr_t)vb;
uintptr_t diff = ua > ub ? ua - ub : ub - ua;
printf("Maybe byte difference of %" PRIuPTR "\n", diff);
```